# Different Web.Config Files For each User on TFS

Tags: .net, debugging, tfs, web-config

I'am able to configure different web.config files (debug & release) on TFS.

Is it possible to configure web.config files for each user separately?
my objective is to include personal connection strings to connect local databases on TFS.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure,
You can same the .config files like so:
You already have Web.Debug.Config and Web.Release.Config out of the box...

So in order to make another unique, based on the configuration type, 
simply create Web..Config, and put in the specific credentials.

Then create the configuration  by going to Configuration Manager.

Comment: thanks @raphael. I tried to configure like this but my project use default web.config still.